# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php

```
if (!isset($partners[$item['partner_id']])) {
    $partner = array_pop(DB::LimitQuery('partner', array(
        'condition' => Array(("id = {$item['partner_id']}")))));        
    $partners[$item['partner_id']] = $partner;      
} else {
    $partner = $partners[$item['partner_id']];
}
```

The above code reports the strict standars warning on line 3. Little help please?

Comment: That is a mighty strange array you are creating. YOu sure you don't mean to use a key/value pair instead?

Comment: [Look at the docs](http://php.net/array-pop) - Notice how the `$array` argument has a `&` before it? That means it expects a reference. Only variables can be references. You're giving it a function return value. Assign the return value to a variable first, then pass that.

Comment: thanks, i figure it out